# R / MSSQL Server / RODBC Select * as character

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, odbc, rodbc

I'm trying to pull the contents of a table in MS SQL Server into R via the RODBC package/connector.  I'd like everything to be read over as a character but can't figure out how to do so.  Currently, I'm just writing using something like this:

```
varsToPull <- c('cast(var1 as varchar(255))','cast(var2 as varchar(255))','cast(var3 as varchar(255))')

sqla <- paste('select top 100 ', paste(varsToPull,collapse = ","), ' from table1',, sep = '')
df1 <- sqlQuery(conn1, sqla)
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: The vignette for working with databases using [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) may be interest.